# Word2Vec running on Local machine(Mac OS) but not on AWS Instance

Tags: machine-learning, word2vec

I used word2vec on a customer review dataset provided by my company and ran it on my local machine - Mac OS Sierra - 10.12.1(Beta) with 8gb RAM. It is working fine. But I wanted to fasten up the process and henceforth tried to run it on an AWS Instance with 16gb RAM. But when I tried to run it there, the program keeps crashing with memory issues or segmentation faults. I tried to provide 16gb of swap memory more. Even that memory gets full and the program crashes.

- Am I missing to do something here?
- Why can't the memory be handled by the server like my MAC?
- Can I do something so that the program successfully runs on my server too?

Note: The code and the dataset is the same on both local machine and the server.

Comment: Could you share some details around the size of the dataset and the code which you are using? I am guessing that you would be using some open-source solution for word2vec.